# Libstdc++.so.6 version GLIBCXX 3.4.18 not found on debian

Tags: linux, qt, libstdc++, debian-based

I’m trying to compile some program in qt creator, gcc version 4.7.2, Astra Linux, x86_64-Linux-gnu and faces this problem. I have already tried everything that could found on internet by the problem is still here. How can I fix this?

Comment: Debian wheezy (oldoldstable): g++-4.7 → libstdc++.so.6.0.17→ no object `GLIBCXX_3.4.18`. Solution : install `gcc-4.8/jessie, g++-4.8/jessie` https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/89243/how-to-install-gcc-4-8-1-on-debian-wheezy ... Still works : Tested on one of my old Debian 7 Wheezy installs.

Comment: Check LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable in your project's "Run settings". And if it does not point to your libstdc++.so.6 library location add it.